# Eclipse can't connect curly braces

Tags: android, eclipse

Im new to android programming and Im following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZaRNVwKAy4. I followed the tutorial exactly but Eclipse manages to find lots of errors. It says the curly braces are incorrect, yet when I select one, the one it corresponds to lights up and they all form a pair. Furthermore, Eclipse doesn't recognise the variables I declared before the onCreate method. Here is the code:

```
package com.example.tutorialproject;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class TutorialOne extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener{

    TextView = textOut;
    EditText = textIn;
    RadioGroup = gravityG, styleG;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial1);

        textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvChange);
        textIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        gravityG = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgGravity);
        styleG = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgStyle);
        Button gen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGenerate);

        gen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v){
                textOut.setText(textIn.getText());
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (checkedId){
        case R.id.rbLeft: 
            textOut.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            break;

        case R.id.rbCenter:
            textOut.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            break;

        case R.id.rbRight:
            textOut.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Cut/paste and clean doesn't work, I already tried it. Anyone any idea what might be the problem? Sorry for the long post.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't take this too harshly but you should go through a basic Java tutorial before tackling Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TextView = textOut;
EditText = textIn;
RadioGroup = gravityG, styleG;
```

get rid of the `=`. You can find here a nice introduction to the [member variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

Comment: Solved it... I don't understand how I could've miss that, thanks